# Evaluate the following integral: $\int_0^{\pi} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sin(nx)\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sin(mx) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

> Show that for $n,m = 1,2,3, ...$:
>
> $$\int_0^{\pi} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sin(nx)\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sin(mx) dx = \delta_{mn},$$
>
> where $\delta_{mn}=\begin{cases} 0 & m \neq n \\ 1 &m=n \end{cases}$.

No matter how hard I try, I cannot get to prove it.

I understand we have to use the factor formula of trigonometry. But I still can't prove it.

Answer (score 2):

**A start:** Use the fact that
$$\sin s\sin t=\frac{\cos(s-t)-\cos(s+t)}{2}.\tag{1}$$

You will also need the easily verified fact that if $q$ is a **non-zero** integer, then 
$$\int_0^{\pi} \cos(qx)\,dx=0.$$

**Added:** We now show that if $m=n$ then 
$$\int_0^\pi \sin mx\sin nx\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}.\tag{2}$$
Letting $s=mx$ and $t=nx$ in (1), and setting $m=n$, we find that the integral (2) is equal to
$$\int_0^\pi \frac{1+\cos(2nx)}{2}\,dx.$$
We are integrating a sum. The integral is
$$\int_0^\pi \frac{1}{2}\,dx+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\pi \cos(2nx)\,dx.$$
The first integral is equal to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. The second integral is equal to $0$. This completes the case $m=n$.

Comment: I still cant get it why m=n the solution is 1 otherwise the solution is 0?

Comment: I will add a little detail.

Comment: What is the formula used in (1)? I thought the factor formula means that you need to divide 2 (for both s-t and s+t)?

Comment: One way to obtain (1) from probably familiar formulas is to note that $\cos(s-t)=\cos s\cos t-\sin s\sin t$ and $\cos(s+t)=\cos s\cos t-\sin s\sin t$. Subtract. We get $2\sin s\sin t$. Division by $2$  gives us $\sin s\sin t$. You may be recalling a sum to product formula rather than product to sum. If you want a list of trig identities, see wikipedia, trigonometric identities. You will find (1), probably with different symbols.